# Which browsers do support flow control feature of HTTP/2?

Tags: javascript, json, html, browser, http2

Recently, some browsers support HTTP/2.
[This picture shows all versions of browsers support HTTP/2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UR9NP.png)

And HTTP/2 has new features such as flow control which is implemented by setting `WINDOW_UPDATE` frame.
Do you know which version of browsers support flow control and allow users to configure `WINDOW_UPDATE` frame by javascript or something else

Answer (score 6):

All browsers support flow control, it's a mandatory part of the spec. [Section 5.2.1 of RFC 7540](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-5.2.1) explicitly says that "Flow control cannot be disabled.". I don't know of any browser that gives any sort of control to the javascript.

HTTP/2 clients for scripting languages such as [Hyper](http://hyper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (in python) or [http-2](https://github.com/igrigorik/http-2) (in ruby) do give fine grained access to the protocol however.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my task is to test that frame on any browsers such as google chrome or firefox.

Comment: Javascript does not currently expose most of the internals of HTTP/2. For example, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40235034/http-2-0-in-browser-how-does-browser-cancel-server-push .